# ZK MVVM binder save with EL-Expression

Tags: mvvm, save, zk

How to do this with zk MVVM

i want to save a bean 
but with condition 
if the type is personal than save into personal, else into company

```html
<textbox value="@save(vm.personal ? vm.masterCifPersonal.cifId : vm.masterCifCompany.cifId)" width="100px" maxlength="10"/>
```

but when binder save into bean, this exception appear

> > Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tip is to modify your code and use a temporary var:

```html
<textbox value="@save(vm.temp)" width="100px" maxlength="10"/>
```

and modify your setter as

```
void setTemp(Long temp) {
    if(personal) {
        masterCifPersonal.cifId = temp;
    } else {
        masterCifCompany.cifId = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution could be :

### ZK 8 and higher :

```
<if test="@load(vm.personal)">
    <textbox value="@save(vm.masterCifPersonal.cifId)"/> 
</if>
<if test="@load(not vm.personal)">
    <textbox value="@save(vm.masterCifCompany.cifId)"/> 
</if>
```

### ZK 6.5 an higher:

```
<textbox value="@save(vm.masterCifPersonal.cifId)" visible="="@load(vm.personal)"/>
<textbox value="@save(vm.masterCifCompany.cifId)" visible="="@load(not vm.personal)"/>
```

### Difference:

The if tag will **not** render the other tag into the dom while using the visible attribute will render it in the dom.
If personal isn't dynamic you could use the `if` attribute of the `Textbox` but the usage is then : `if="${vm.personal}` **because binding will not work**
Like this the textbox isn't also rendered into the DOM.